# Is it possible to create an image of a full view controller (not just what's on screen at once)?

Tags: swift, xcode, image, uiview, uiviewcontroller

This is the code I'm using at the moment:

```
func configureMailController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    self.view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["emailaddress@email.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Form")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Here's the image", isHTML: true)
    let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenShot!)! as NSData
    mailComposerVC.addAttachmentData(imageData as Data, mimeType: "image/png", fileName: "imageName")
    return mailComposerVC
}
```

This code emails an image of screenShot, however I need it to be a much larger image showing the whole viewController not just the bottom part which is on screen when the action is activated.

Is it possible to adjust this code to do so, I tried changing the code from using my UIView to my UIScrollView however that didn't work either, in fact that didn't even produce an image.

UPDATE: I've attached a video to show what is currently happening.

[image]

Comment: Do you have examples of the screenshots that you are currently getting? - do you have a navigationController or tabBarController to consider?

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code on one of my projects and the whole view controller was captured just fine, *the only thing that was missing was my navigation bar from the navigation controller.*

If you want to capture the `navigationBar` or `tabBar` you need to make sure you choose the correct view to render, here is an example that checks if the `navigationController` exists and grabs the `navigationController`'s view

```
func configureMailController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let nav = self.navigationController!
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(nav.view.bounds.size);
    nav.view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["emailaddress@email.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Form")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Here's the image", isHTML: true)
    let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenShot!)! as NSData
    mailComposerVC.addAttachmentData(imageData as Data, mimeType: "image/png", fileName: "imageName")
    return mailComposerVC
}
```

Hope that helps, would still like to see the screenshots you have ended up with so that I can be sure of your problem.

---

Update: Now you have added the video I can see that you are using a scrollView. I've not tested this but you'll want to start by telling the graphics context to use the `contentSize` from the scrollView

*What I'm not sure about is wether this will capture all of your scrollViews content as we are still using the navigationControllers view to render.*

You may have to tell you scrollView not to clip it's contents and also send the scrollView back to the top like this:

```
...

self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = false
self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:0), animated: false)

let nav = self.navigationController!
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.scrollView.contentSize);
nav.view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

...
```

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try and get the screenshots as soon as I can but I've somehow managed to mess up the storyboard and now xcode is completely unresponsive when trying to change it back so it looks like I'm going to have to redo a lot of my project before I can send the screenshots.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, I've finally fixed my project. I've updated my original post with a video to show what it happening when I run the app.
I didn't have a navBar before but I do now so I'll have to add the changes you described, however I'm still having the same issue where it doesn't show the full ViewController.

Comment: One more update, I've used the exact same code as yourself to see if that would change anything. However I can't run it because I'm getting an error _Missing return in a function expected to return 'MFMailComposerViewController'_ on the final } . Do you have any idea why I'm getting that? I've tried a couple things but can't find an answer.

Comment: Hey I’ve updated the answer to prevent that missing return error.

Comment: Great thanks! I just ran that code and the navBar was captured, however there is still the issue that it's not the full viewController. So still the same as the video I posted.

Comment: I see the issue now, I have updated my answer again.

Comment: I just ran the new code and it creates an image of the top of the view controller. However again it's one screen length. Is there a way to increase the image length to cover the whole viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer from @Wez:

Using the code below creates an image of the whole scroll view.

```
...

self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = false
self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:0), animated: false)

let scroll = self.scrollView!
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.scrollView.contentSize);
scroll.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

...
```

However, this doesn't include the navigation bar. For my purpose it's not necessary to have the navigation bar but if someone does find a way to include it that would be great.

Comment: I think you need to realise why this happens instead of just asking for more and more help, because I think you can probably make this work on your own.. 1. The context needs to be the same size as the content you want to render, it's currently not big enough to include the nav bar. 2. You need to ensure that everything you want to render is visible in the view that you choose to run the `.render` method on, this means ensuring that content is not being clipped on any of the parent views.

Comment: @Wez you’re absolutely right that I need to understand what is happening. Up until my last answer I didn’t really understand how it all worked. Your comment has confirmed that it is working the way I thought it was, but I tried to change a few things to include the nav bar and couldn’t get it working. That’s why I put up the answer i did asking about the extra info as I couldn’t figure it out. But I understand I do need to learn myself instead of asking questions too quickly.